# drawing snake decoration in a box tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, decorations

I am trying to draw some snake decorations in a box using `tikz` library but couldn't achieve what I want. Why there is mis-alignment between the actual markings and the snakes. I am using the following code for this.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing, shapes, arrows, shadows, positioning}

\newcommand{\tikzmark}[2]{%
 \tikz[overlay,remember picture] \node[text=black,
       inner sep=2pt] (#1) {#2};}

 \begin{document}

 \begin{figure}[ht]
 \centering
 \tikzstyle{box}=[draw, fill=pink!10, text centered, drop shadow]
 \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture]
 \node (main) [box, minimum height=20em, minimum width=10em,align=left] 
 {
  \tikzmark{a}{}xxxxxxxx\tikzmark{b}{}\\
  \tikzmark{c}{}xxxxxxxx\tikzmark{d}{}\\
 };

 \draw [-,decorate,decoration=snake] (a.center) -- (b.center);
 \draw [-,decorate,decoration=snake] (c.center) -- (d.center);
 \end{tikzpicture}
 \end{figure}
 \end{document}
```

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve? If we knew your goal, it'd be easier to know what to do.

Comment: @Alenanno I simply want to draw snake decorations in place of text 'xxxxxxxxxxx'.

Answer (score 1):

May be you have to adjust the baseline in

```
\newcommand{\tikzmark}[2]{%
 \tikz[baseline=-0.5ex,overlay,remember picture] \node[text=black,
       inner sep=2pt] (#1) {#2};}
```

to get

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing, shapes, arrows, shadows, positioning}

\newcommand{\tikzmark}[2]{%
 \tikz[baseline=-0.5ex,overlay,remember picture] \node[text=black,
       inner sep=2pt] (#1) {#2};}

 \begin{document}

 \begin{figure}[ht]
 \centering
 \tikzstyle{box}=[draw, fill=pink!10, text centered, drop shadow]
 \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture]
 \node (main) [box, minimum height=20em, minimum width=10em,align=left]
 {
  \tikzmark{a}{}xxxxxxxx\tikzmark{b}{}\\
  \tikzmark{c}{}xxxxxxxx\tikzmark{d}{}\\
 };

 \draw [-,decorate,decoration=snake] (a.center) -- (b.center);
 \draw [-,decorate,decoration=snake] (c.center) -- (d.center);
 \end{tikzpicture}
 \end{figure}
 \end{document}
```

Comment: Even after copy-pasting the above code, I am not getting the same output as posted in your image. Between, the output in the image is what I exactly want.

Comment: @Shahzad You have to compile 2-3 times.

Comment: Yes. I did compiled for several times but its not producing the desired output.

Comment: @Shahzad Are you using the latest tikz? i.e. version 3?

Comment: Yes. Its version 3.0.0.

Comment: @Shahzad: Try compiling the above code as such. Does it work? It works for me, hence hard to guess.