# Shade an area on one side of the curve with the boundary of the irregular shading

Tags: tikz-pgf, shading, fillbetween, fill

I need to recreate this graph, with those shading on both sides of the curve, both with the line pattern down the curve, and the shading up the curve.

[image]

Note that both limits of the shading are not uniform lines.

Could you help me exactly recreate the jagged edges?

This is the code I was able to write

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz, pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,shapes,arrows,calc,intersections,pgfplots.fillbetween,patterns,patterns.meta,graphs,backgrounds,matrix,mindmap,decorations.markings,decorations.pathreplacing,decorations.pathmorphing}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.7]
% Axis
\draw [->] (0,0) node [below] {0} -- (0,0) -- (5.5,0) node [below] {$x_1$};
\draw [->] (0,0) node [below] {0} -- (0,0) -- (0,5.5) node [above] {$x_2$};
% Indifference curve
\path[name path=A] (0.3,5) to [out=280,in=175] (5.5,0.5);
\path[draw,red,name path=B] (1,5) to [out=280,in=175] (5.5,1.2);
\path[name path=C] (1.6,5) to [out=280,in=175] (5.5,1.8);

\tikzfillbetween[of=A and B][pattern={Lines[angle=45,distance=6pt]}];
\tikzfillbetween[of=B and C]{balck, opacity=0.1};
%doesn't work
%\addplot [pattern={Lines[angle=45,distance=6pt]}] fill between[of=A and B];
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I could improve what I had done and I could get this

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz, pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,shapes,arrows,calc,intersections,pgfplots.fillbetween,patterns,patterns.meta,graphs,backgrounds,matrix,mindmap,decorations.markings,decorations.pathreplacing,decorations.pathmorphing}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]
\draw [-latex] (0,0) node [below] {0} -- (0,0) -- (5.5,0) node [below] {$x_1$};
\draw [-latex] (0,0) node [below] {0} -- (0,0) -- (0,5.5) node [left] {$x_2$};
\path[decorate,decoration={snake,segment length=20, amplitude = 0.8pt},name path=A] (0.3,5) to [out=280,in=175] (5.5,0.5);
\path[draw,thick,name path=B] (1,5) to [out=280,in=175] (5.5,1.2);
\path[decorate,decoration={snake, segment length=20, amplitude = 0.5pt},name path=C] (1.6,5) to [out=280,in=175] (5.5,1.8);
\node at (0,0) [black,above right]{$\lbrace y \in\mathbb{R}^2_+:x \succsim y\rbrace$};
\node at (2.5,4) [black,above right]{$\lbrace y \in\mathbb{R}^2_+:y \succsim x\rbrace$};
\node at (4,2.5) [black,right]{$\lbrace y \in\mathbb{R}^2_+:y \sim x\rbrace$};
\tikzfillbetween[of=A and B]{pattern={Lines[angle=45,distance=2pt, thick]}};
\tikzfillbetween[of=B and C]{balck, opacity=0.1};
\fill[black,circle,scale=0.3] [midway]B;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

however i can't get draw the "x" in the middle of curve, and neither can't draw the arrow from the label next to curve.

exist any other method to draw the curve with a sinuous line? I read a post [Truncate tikz snake decoration without changing frequency](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/337326/truncate-tikz-snake-decoration-without-changing-frequency) that solution is to use a sin function, but I can't understand how it draw a curve whit that